# HTTP request Ruby

Tags: ruby, http

I'm doing a tutorial online and I have a challenge to read through a text file and file the one and only name that is a Palindrome. However the file containing the names is in this url `http://www.codequizzes.com/challenges/names.txt`. I'm pretty new to this http request stuff. How can I require the contents of this text file with a basic ruby program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using [Net::HTTP](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html)? (There are other libraries, but this one is built in and simple enough.)

```
require 'net/http'

text = Net::HTTP.get(URI('http://www.codequizzes.com/challenges/names.txt'))
```

Comment: BTW, I found this by searching for "ruby http request". As you learn to code, try to get used to doing this kind of search yourself. With practice, you'll know what to search for and how to skim the results you find.

Answer (score 1):

This will copy a remote file to a local file...

```
require "open-uri"

remote_resource = "http://www.codequizzes.com/challenges/names.txt"

remote_data = open(remote_resource).read

local_file = open("local_names.txt", "w") 

local_file.write(remote_data)
local_file.close
```